# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: Upon Folder Path

Tags: python

Trying to save a downloaded image to a path (inside a folder). It works with no folder, and I have tried relative and absolute paths.

```
import requests
import os
import progressbar

b_url = "http://cdn2-img.pressreader.com/pressdisplay/docserver/getimage.aspx?file=9b342017090100000000001001&page={}&scale=100"

print("Format your url like this:")
print(b_url)
print("Note the {}\n")
print("Images will be written to the directory `PressReader`")
url = input("URL: ")
if url == "":
  url = b_url
name = input("Article name: ")
page_length = 84
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()
for page in bar(range(0, page_length+1)):
  if not os.path.exists("PressReader"):
    os.makedirs("PressReader")
  r = requests.get(url.format(page), stream=True)
  if r.status_code == 200:
with open(r'"PressReader\{}-Page-{}.png"'.format(name, page), 'wb') as f:
  for chunk in r:
    f.write(chunk)
```

This should make a folder `PressReader` (which it does), then download the images to that folder.

It however breaks, with this error:

```
line 23, in <module>
with open(r'"PressReader\{}-Page-{}.png"'.format(name, page), 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"PressReader\\e-Page-1.png"'
```

Comment: dont use double quotes again, just this `with open(r'PressReader\{}-Page-{}.png'.format(name, page), 'wb') as f:`

Comment: Just to spell out the previous comment, there is no folder named `"PressReader` with a double quote, and you probably don't want a literal double quote at the end of `.png"` either